# Unable to use oculus Triger button to disable game object with use of XR-interaction toolkit

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus

I am trying to create a simple app for oculus quest 2 from unity with use of XR-Interaction toolkit ,
i wanted to disable the game object when i pressed trigger button , i added XR simple intractable to the game object and called Active method

[image]

But in play mode when i pressed Triger button its not working but its works when i hold the grip button and press Triger.

i wanted to disable only by clicking trigger button,

could anyone please help me is there any way to remove dependency from trigger button with grip

i Checked the XR input Action the the Active is set to button

[image]